# Reagent on creating element with infinite seq as args

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

Based on [this](https://reagent-project.github.io/news/news050.html) on **More equality** section, is it still possible to create a component which accepts an infinite seq as args?

```
(defn my-div 
  [& args]
  (let [[params args] (if (-> args first map?)
                        [(first args) (next args)]
                        [nil args])]
    (into [:div (merge {:class "defaul-class"} params)]
          args)))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the same reference you provide, in the section on More Equality, it states

Note: This is a breaking change! It means that you can no longer pass infinite seqs to a component.

So I would assume the answer to your question is no. When you think about it and consider what the component is doing, this seems to make perfect sense.